# Ajax error Object object in dotnet when returning an Json

Tags: ajax, razor, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

i got an ajax call on an cshtml file:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: `@Url.Action("LoadChartData", "Sensor")`,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get",
            async: "false",
            data: "plaindata",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (d){
                $.each(d, function(index, item){
                    data.addRows([item.tag, item.value]);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert("Error " + xhr);
            }
        });
```

In the LoadCharData method, i reed an file from an txt and convert this to Json to return

```
        public JsonResult LoadChartData()
        {
            List<ChartData> items = new List<ChartData>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("./Data/ChartData.txt"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChartData>>(json);
            }

            return Json(new {data = items});
        }
```

When i go to the rote, the ajax returns an error Object object. I dont know how to inspect this or check the value.
If i send an request to the JsonResult method using insominia, the data returns perfect.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: can you do `console.log(d)` or `alert(d)` inside your success function of ajax and see what it prints